# How to use draggable and sortable jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

how draggable with sortable  jquery.. i want dragimage is drag and aslo item move .......................................

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="smallitems">

  <div class="dragimage">
    <a href="#select1" class="lablecircle active">1</a>
 </div>
 <div class="dragimage">
    <a href="#select1" class="lablecircle">2</a>
 </div>
 <div class="dragimage">
    <a href="#select3" class="lablecircle">3</a>
 </div>
  <div class="dragimage">
    <a href="#select4" class="lablecircle">4</a>
 </div>
 <div class="dragimage">
    <a href="#select5" class="lablecircle">5</a>
 </div>
 <div class="dragimage">
    <a href="#select1" class="lablecircle">6</a>
 </div>
 <div class="dragimage">
    <a href="#select7" class="lablecircle">7</a>
 </div>
 <div class="dragimage">
    <a href="#select8" class="lablecircle">8</a>
 </div>
</div>    
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"><span class="lablecircle" id="select1">1</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="lablecircle" id="select2">2</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="lablecircle" id="select3">3</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="lablecircle" id="select4">4</span></div>
     <div class="item"><span class="lablecircle" id="select5">5</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="lablecircle" id="select6">6</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="lablecircle" id="select7">7</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="lablecircle" id="select8">8</span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This orginal.. before dragable...

[image]

This orginal.. after dragable...

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/4p3Aa/

Comment: i wanted dragimageClass is drag and anotehr item is auto drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use jQuery UI, also I suppose you know about it and meant it when mentioning *sortable jQuery*. With jQuery UI the code can be simple like this:

```
var oldIndex;
$('.smallitems').sortable({
  start: function(e,ui){
    oldIndex = ui.item.index();
  },
  stop: function(e,ui){
    var newIndex = ui.item.index();
    var largeItems = $('.items').children();
    if(newIndex > oldIndex)
        largeItems.eq(newIndex).after(largeItems[oldIndex]);
    else 
        largeItems.eq(newIndex).before(largeItems[oldIndex]);
  }
});
```

We can save the `oldIndex` of the dragged item in the `sortstart` event handler, then in the `sortstop` event handler, we can get the `newIndex`, from the index changes, we can re-locate the new item in the large list easily via `.after` and `.before` methods.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/4p3Aa/1/)

Comment: yes thank but i want dragimage is drag fade ....

Comment: yes i like taht. your answer very good..

Comment: @user3755049 what do you mean `speed`? this code's performance is not that bad.

Comment: @user3755049 if you want some fading effect, check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/4p3Aa/2/)

Comment: hello i use jqery 1.11.0 now ... how use version conflit

Comment: @user3755049 you can just use jQuery 1.11.0, but in jsFiddle it has no option to also include jQuery UI, however in your actual code you can include the jQuery UI separately, here in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/4p3Aa/3/ I just used jQuery 1.11.0 but included jQuery UI 1.10 as an external resource.

Comment: oh! yes thank you i am study you answer..

Comment: hellow , if not use plugin..  how use sotrable and dragable.. do you think it is possible..

Comment: @user3755049 of course plugin is just a bunch of pure JS code, so if it's possible with a plugin, it's also possible with pure JS. However doing so may require a lot of code (and attempt to fix bug). In this case I think writing the code yourself is not easy, it requires fairly much code.

Comment: but your plugin(jqury-ui-min) is very big....

Comment: i use your answer How using another samll ui plugin ....

Comment: tha is ok? sure.. you answer is good..

Comment: @user3755049 if you just want the `sortable` feature, you can just download that part (using custom download feature from jQuery UI homepage), I've just downloaded it and uploaded it to a new site here for you https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqzslipcbvg1nl4/jquery-ui-1.10.4.sortable.min.js?dl=1 (just about 37KB), and here is the new demo using that plugin http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/4p3Aa/5/

Comment: @user3755049 also note that the plugin can be cached, that means it's not downloaded for every page user requests from your server, once it's downloaded, it will be cached and the next requests won't have to download it again.

Comment: yes my friends ... thank you very much about for your helpe me...